# Taylor expansion of function

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

I try to figure out how the taylor expansion of the following function looks like, but so far I wasn't successfull:

$z↦e^{iuz}−1−iuz$ for $|z|<1$.

Who has an idea?

Comment: Why the levy-processes tag?

Comment: What is the definition of "Taylor expansion"?  What happens if you try to apply it to this function?  To avoid having your question put "on hold", you need to show some of your own work.

Comment: @ Semiclassical I need it in the conext of the proof of levy-khintchine. I want to show that the levy-khintchine representation is the characteristic function of a infinitely divisible probability measure.

Comment: @OkePetersen: You know about the Levy-Khintchine theorem but you have troubles with the Taylor series of the exponential? Wow! Just wow!

Comment: @ Alex M. Look in the comments of the answer. Is it possible to solve it for you?

Comment: I started a new thread in which the whole problem is stated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789635/explain-inequality-of-integrals-by-taylor-expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{iuz}-1-iuz=1+iuz-\frac{u^2z^2}2-\ldots-1-iuz=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{i^nu^nz^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Thank you, I also have this result. I was asking this because it said that from the taylor expansion the following will follow:

$$|\int_{|y|<1} e^{iuy}−1−iuy\ \, v(dy)| \le 0.5\int_{|y|<1} |uy|^2\ \,v(dy)$$

My problem is that I still don't know why it follows.

Comment: @OkePetersen Your question didn't even mention integration and the only tag I can see is Taylor Expansion...

Comment: I thought it follows directly, but it is not obvious for me. So I stated the original problem.

Comment: I started a new thread in which the whole problem is stated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789635/explain-inequality-of-integrals-by-taylor-expansion.